# Different type of \sum symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols, amsmath, math-operators, amssymb

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I need (picture taken from a beamer document):

[image]

I'd like to know the font that is being used in the second picture for the **\sum** command. Some of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
        \alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \alpha_i
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: where did you get the image, is it a digital document?

Comment: Yes, from a beamer document

Comment: the you can see exactly which font is used from the pdf or tex source, don't make us guess from an image. Note you should choose a font for the whol character set not just a single character

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that!